# how to perform arithmetic operation on string in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have values like below in `dealer_price(type string)` field:

```
| dealer_price |

| -------- |

| 1000.00|

| 5000.00|

| Contact for pricing|

| 10000.00|
```

I have queries something like below to perform arithmetic operation:

```
select (dealer_price + 10) AS cust_price FROM my_table
```

I want to check `field_type` of each row in query if `field_type` is string then display string only and is numeric then perform arithmetic operation. right now above query considering string as 0 and perform operation. basically want output like below using query:

```
| cust_price |

| -------- |

| 1010.00|

| 5010.00|

| Contact for pricing|

| 10010.00|
```

Comment: How to perform arithmetic operation on a string? Simply put, don't do it. Use proper data types for each column. It's important to normalize data and, as is, this table does not conform to 1NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case statement to check the `dealer_price` value's data type:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN dealer_price REGEXP '^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$' THEN dealer_price + 10
        ELSE dealer_price
    END AS cust_price
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: arithmetic operation not working

Comment: for decimal check REGEX '^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$' worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN dealer_price REGEXP '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$'
            THEN CAST(CAST(dealer_price AS UNSIGNED) + 10 AS varchar(255))
            ELSE dealer_price END AS cust_price
FROM my_table;
```

Note that all branches of a `CASE` expression need to have the same type.  In this case, that type must be string/text.  Therefore we need to first cast numeric values of `dealer_price` to integer, increment by 10, and then cast back to text.

Also note that it is generally bad practice to mix numeric and non numeric data in the same column.

Comment: Tim its giving me an syntax error.

Comment: @Badal Solanki I suppose it's the data type in the `cast` function to blame. The int must be defined as signed or unsigned. Try `CAST(dealer_price AS unsigned)`

Answer (score 0):

If "Contact..." is the only non-numeric value in that column, then change to

```
DECIMAL(11,2) NULL
```

And use the convention that `NULL` means "Contact...".

I think that `NULL + 10` yields `NULL`.  Hence the arithmetic automagically works.

For outputting the value, do

```
 SELECT ... COALESCE(dealer_price, "Contact ...") AS 'Dealer Price'
```